# Get row value on click from TextView in Table layout Android

Tags: android

```
TextView Edit = new TextView(this);
Edit.setClickable(true);
Edit.setPaintFlags(Edit.getPaintFlags()| Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
Edit.setText("Edit");

Edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(ViewTransactions.this,
                            UpdateTransaction.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("Id",acd);
        Toast.makeText(ViewTransactions.this, "This is my Toast message!"+ acd,
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();
    }
});

Edit.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
Edit.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
Edit.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
//Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
Ll.addView(Edit, params);
tr.addView((View) Ll);
```

I have created a TableRow dynamically but I wish to get the id of the TableRow that is clicked from the TextView within the TableRow. However, everytime I click on edit or delete, it will take the last row of the table instead of the row i have chosen. I have seen other forums but theirs is on the whole row instead of a specific cell aka TextView  [how my table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL8nQ.png)

[image]

Comment: You might be better off using a listview.

Comment: I have done a lot for my table and I have  no time to change it to listview well as you already noticed that im on to update and delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save each row's id as a tag in your "Edit" TextView

```
 Edit.setTag(rowId);
```

then retrieve it when it is clicked

```
 Edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int rowId = (int) v.getTag();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the onClick method:

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               String textFromView = ((TextView) v).getText();
               //TODO now do whatever you will with the text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    Android.Widget.TableRow row = (Android.Widget.TableRow)tableLayout.GetChildAt(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
        TextView cell = (TextView) row.GetChildAt(j);
        var value = cell.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?